# Pandas fillna() not filling values from series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill missing values in a column in a DataFrame with the value from another DataFrame's column. Here's the setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [2, 3, 5, np.nan, np.nan],
    'b': [10, 11, 13, 14, 15]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1]
})
```

I can of course do this and it works:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(1)
```

However, this results in the missing values not being filled:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df2['x'])
```

And this results in an error:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df2['x'].values)
```

How can I use the value from `df2['x']` to fill in missing values in `df['a']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one general solution is select first value by `[0]` for scalar:

```
print (df2['x'].values[0])
1

df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df2['x'].values[0])
#similar solution for select by loc
#df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df2.loc[0, 'x'])
print (df)
     a   b
0  2.0  10
1  3.0  11
2  5.0  13
3  1.0  14
4  1.0  15
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can guarantee `df2['x']` only has a single element, then use `.item`:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df2.values.item())
```

Or,

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df2['x'].item())
```

```
df
     a   b
0  2.0  10
1  3.0  11
2  5.0  13
3  1.0  14
4  1.0  15
```

Otherwise, this isn't possible unless they're either the same length and/or index-aligned.

As a rule of thumb; either

1. pass a scalar, or
2. pass a dictionary mapping the index of the NaN value to its replacement value (e.g., `df.a.fillna({3 : 1, 4 : 1})`), or
3. index aligned series